# MongoEngine specifying an ID

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, nosql

I'm having trouble getting MongoEngine to accept specific IDs. It seems absolutely determined to use (and only use) `ObjectId`s. I'm more than able to generate my own IDs in this instance, thanks.

How can I get MongoEngine to play nice?

Comment: I'm having trouble answering your question, because you haven't shown any code exhibiting the problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I managed to solve this by adding the following to the class:

```
id = mongoengine.StringField(required=True, primary_key=True)
```

Not sure if this is the "proper" way of doing things, so ill leave this unanswered for a bit.

Comment: What was your problem.  What did you add to fix it?  How would someone besides you comprehend your problem?   Are you saying you didn't have any field acting as an id at all before and couldn't figure out why mongoengine wasn't allowing you to use an ad hoc id field?

Comment: I could specify the id field even if it wasn't specified, but it wouldn't accept a string/unicode id, only ObjectId.

Comment: @NoahMcIlraith has this been resolved in later versions of mongoengine? I am currently using 0.9.0 and facing the same problem however this worked for me.